# Finding the frequency that one s-expression appears in another

Tags: scheme, racket, counter, frequency

I am working on a small personal project to teach myself Racket. I am currently creating a function which takes in two s-expressions, and returns the number of times that the first expression appears in the second.

The program works as expected if I input something like 1 and `'(1 2 3 1 2 3)` and returns 2, but does does not work for `'(1 2)` and `((1 2) 1 2 (1) (2) (1 2))` which should return 2.

Here is the code that I have so far

```
(define (count item lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((= item (car lst)) (+ 1 (count item (cdr lst))))
        (else (count item (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (count item lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((equal? item (car lst)) (+ 1 (count item (cdr lst))))
        (else (count item (cdr lst)))))
```

Remember, `=` is for comparing *numbers*. For a more general equality comparison, use `equal?`. Now it works as expected:

```
(count '(1 2) '((1 2) 1 2 (1) (2) (1 2)))
=> 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not even think of about how the = sign works in Racket.